# Combing two objects of class ranger in R for survival analysis

Tags: r, classification, regression, survival-analysis, ensemble-learning

I am working on the R package [ranger](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ranger/index.html) which is an implementation of random forest ensemble. I want to grow several sub forests and then combine them as one object to use for predicting new data. There is a `combine()` function within the `randomForest` R package but I want to do this for the `ranger` R package.
An example of two sub forests could be

```
require(survival)
require(ranger)
rf1 <- ranger(Surv(time, status) ~ ., data = veteran,num.tree=10)
rf2 <- ranger(Surv(time, status) ~ ., data = veteran,num.tree=10)

rf <- a function to combine rf1 and rf2.
```

I need such a function. Can anybody help?

Comment: Unfortunately, such a function will not be easy as you have to re-create randomForest's [`combine`](https://github.com/cran/randomForest/blob/master/R/combine.R) to align to ranger. Maybe raise an issue on the [ranger git repo](https://github.com/imbs-hl/ranger) for authors to incorporate in later releases.